# Unable to connect database using ADO.NET entity data model when website is hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

I am using an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** (`.edmx`) approach in my website. It's working fine in local system but when I hosted this application in IIS, I am not able to connect to the database. There's a problem with my server connection string. Please let me know how to resolve this issue and how to make sure my server connection string is valid.

This is my local system connection string:

```
<add name="myconnectionstring" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.db.csdl|res://*/App_Code.db.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.db.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myservername;
         Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True; 
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is my server connection string:

```
<add name="myconnectionstring" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.db.csdl|res://*/App_Code.db.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.db.msl;
        provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
        provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myservername\SQLEXPRESS;
             Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True; 
             MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: delete existing data model (.edmx file) and connection string from web.config and create new .edmx file it will ask to save connection string to web.config and automatic generates connection string for you. now run your application. i hope it will work.

Comment: Try removing \SQLEXPRESS, if that doesn't work make sure your appPool (id you are running the app from) has security to access the database you are connecting to.

Comment: sanjeet,my .edmx file is working in local but it's not working in server.so my edmx file is correct.problem in server.pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

When you are execution your program on your local computer, you use your User to connect to your database. When you publish on your Webserver with IIS (I'm assuming you are using IIS 7.0), the default user will be "IUSR". With this information, you need to verify if the IIS user as access to the database in the security setting of the server.

Comment: could you explain step by step?